# How can a policy be assigned to AWS resource?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-iam, aws-serverless, aws-sam

Below is my understanding on assigning policy:

[image]

AWS policy can be assigned to user, group, role but **not to** AWS resource.

In aws policy definition, `Principal` entry has value as user, group or role but not AWS resource(like EC2, serverless lambda etc...)

---

Policy can be assigned to a resource via a role

---

We are creating lambda resource(AWS) using SAM template, as shown below:

```
Resources:
  MyFunction:
    Type: 'AWS::Serverless::Function'
    Properties:
      CodeUri: src/
      Handler: index.handler
      Runtime: nodejs4.3
      Policies:

        - SQSPollerPolicy:
            QueueName: name

        - LambdaInvokePolicy:
            FunctionName: name
```

---

but I see `Policies` property as part of the resource definition

---

How can a policy  be assigned to a AWS resource(lambda)?

Comment: Because it is resource level policy, not identity based policy that is shown in your picture.

Comment: Any resource based policy will have `Principal` entity mentioned... `SQSPollerPolicy` does not have `Principal` entity mentioned

Comment: @MatusDubrava and as per this [documentation](https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#awsserverlessfunction), one cannot assign resource based policy...

Comment: Of course, Lambda doesn't support resource based policy, I have completely misread the question. Sorry, my bad.

Comment: @MatusDubrava related question https://stackoverflow.com/q/57049666/3317808

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In aws policy definition, Principal entry has value as user, group or role but not AWS resource(like EC2, serverless lambda etc...)

**Edit**:

I am not sure whether we talk about the same entity in the AWS JSON Policy language here. A policy can be either of type (a) identity-based policy, (b)  trust policy or (c) resource-based policy. [2]

The docs state that "you cannot use the Principal element in an IAM identity-based policy". [2]
Lambda typically uses the other two types of policies: trust policy for the execution role and resource-based policy for cross-account access and access from other AWS services. [6]
However, there is also the option to use identity-based policies with Lambda. [7]
In this case, you do not specify a *Principal*, since "the principal is implicitly the user that the policy is attached to" [2].

**Example:**

In the AWS IAM concept, the *Principal* of a role can also be an AWS service - they are so called *service-roles* [1]. [2]
To set Lambda as principal, you set the following as *AssumeRolePolicyDocument* (trust policy):

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

There is a step-by-step example as an AWS security blog post which shows how to create an execution role for a lambda function manually. [3]

> How can a policy be assigned to a AWS resource(lambda)?

The policy is assigned to the Lambda's execution role. The function then assumes the role during runtime and is granted permission based on all policies which are assigned to the execution role. [4]

> but I see Policies property as part of the resource definition

SAM is able to create the lambda's execution role for you and assign policies to it automatically. The SAM developers provide so called *AWS SAM Policy Templates* [5] which you can reference in your SAM template. By using these policy templates, you instruct SAM to create the policy for you and attach it to the execution role automatically.

#### References

[1] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_terms-and-concepts.html#iam-term-service-role
[2] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_principal.html (section "AWS service")
[3] https://aws.amazon.com/de/blogs/security/how-to-create-an-aws-iam-policy-to-grant-aws-lambda-access-to-an-amazon-dynamodb-table/
[4] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-intro-execution-role.html
[5] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-policy-templates.html
[6] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/access-control-resource-based.html
[7] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/access-control-identity-based.html

Comment: I just copied the views from this [aws_talk](https://youtu.be/Du478i9O_mc?t=564), where he says..."when we create IAM policy, we know, who the `Principal` is...", it is attached to the user, role, group or service... But when you define resource based policy, you should explicitly mention `Principal`

Comment: At 10:40 he talks about service-roles ;)

Comment: At 10:40, he gave an example of service name(`ec2.amazonaws.com`) as `Principal` defined in resource policy but not in permission policy

Comment: your third reference link is pretty cool... Can you also comment on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57028572/could-not-get-the-syntax-of-policy-definition-in-sam-template-resourceserverles)?

Comment: Am accepting this answer just for links 3, 4, & 5. I do not agree with first part of your answer

Comment: When you say.. "The policy is assigned to the Lambda's execution role.", Do you mean, the policy that I wrote in SAM template will over write existing `AWSLambdaExecutionRole` policy definitions?

Comment: [6] says... *AWS Lambda supports resource-based permissions policies for Lambda functions* but how do I prove myself that AWS Lambda does not support identity-based policy?

Comment: Honestly, I do not use SAM, but I think what it does is: for each function you specify, it creates a new role. Then, it creates (probably ?inline?) policies for each statement you define in your template (i.e. SQSPollerPolicy, LambdaInvokePolicy) inside the newly created role. I do not know which definitions could be overwritten? But as I said, I am not using SAM so maybe I am missing something here...

Comment: Lambda supports identity-based policies, see [7] =)
but they are used to control access to the lambda function (i.e. who is able to execute the lambda function), not what the lambda function is able to access

Comment: Check this policy written for AWS managed  (`AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole`), [here](https://gist.github.com/garystafford/846835aa341783ca816d0c88771bcb71). It is not using resource based policy(I mean no `Principal` element)

Comment: The link you posted is most-likely an identity-based policy. It can be attached to the lambda's execution role and will then grant the lambda function permission to write logs to CloudWatch. But!! It has to be attached to the role to do anyhing!

Comment: But you said... [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57023953/how-can-a-policy-be-assigned-to-aws-resource/57028208?noredirect=1#comment100587379_57028208), "identity-based policy does not tell  lambda function what to access...they are used to control access to the lambda function" which conflicts [policy definition](https://gist.github.com/garystafford/846835aa341783ca816d0c88771bcb71)

Comment: Oh I see which conflict you mean here... I meant an identity-based policy which references the Lambda function in the Resource section is used to control access to a lambda function. An identity based policy which is assigned to the lambda execution role is of course used to define which services can be accessed by the lambda function.

Comment: This [process](https://aws.amazon.com/de/blogs/security/how-to-create-an-aws-iam-policy-to-grant-aws-lambda-access-to-an-amazon-dynamodb-table/), did not highlight on... when to use resource-based policy vs identity-based policy for Lambda functions

Comment: Do you want me to agree this: "Lambda typically uses the other two types of policies:" in your answer...

Comment: I did not want to discuss which way of defining permissions is better or used more often. If you have a better wording, please suggest an edit. I think we discussed the topic of this question "How can a policy be assigned to AWS resource?" thoroughly at this point =)

Answer (score 1):

When you define a Serverless Function, SAM **automatically** creates the IAM Role required to run the function. Let's say your function needs to access couple of DynamoDB tables, you need to give your function explicit permissions to access the tables. You can do this by adding AWS Managed Policies to Serverless Function resource definition in your SAM template.

Reference:

https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/docs/policy_templates.rst